# To count the number of characters in a 2-Dimensional String

Tags: c, arrays, string

**Practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[][30]={
                   "My name is Abcd Efgh Jklm.",
                   "I Graduated from BIT.",
                   "I now live in Balochistan."
                 };
  int strcount=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
  int i=0;
  int count=0;         

  for(;i<strcount;++i)
  {
    while(str[i][count] != '\0')
      ++count;

    printf("\n\nNumber of Characters in STR[%d] = %d",i,count);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output of the above stated program is as follows:**

```
Number of Characters in STR[0] = 26

Number of Characters in STR[1] = 26

Number of Characters in STR[2] = 26
```

**Test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[][30]={
                   "My name is Abcd Efgh Jklm.",
                   "I Graduated from BIT.",
                   "I now live in Balochistan."
                 };
  int strcount=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
  int i=0;         

  for(;i<strcount;++i)
  {
    int count=0;
    while(str[i][count] != '\0')
      ++count;

    printf("\n\nNumber of Characters in STR[%d] = %d",i,count);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output of the above stated program is as follow:**

```
Number of Characters in STR[0] = 26

Number of Characters in STR[1] = 21

Number of Characters in STR[2] = 26
```

I made a little modification in the program `Test.c` by changing the position of variable `count`,and placed it in the `for loop`, the output was as desired. 
I recon that this behavior of `count` is due to its position, means where it is declared (inside the `for loop` or outside).

**My question:**
1]Why `count`, when placed outside the `for loop` displays `26` as the output for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause in your `Practice.c` you're only incrementing count for the first string. Then it stays 26 ...

```
for(;i<strcount;++i)
{
    while(str[i][count] != '\0') //<-- when i == 1 count is already 26
       ++count;
     printf("\n\nNumber of Characters in STR[%d] = %d",i,count);
}
```

**REEDITED**: After consulting some similar SO topics I found that the `C` standard states that any partially-complete array initialization is to be padded with zero for the remaining elements. So my previous remark about this code triggering undefined behavior was clearly wrong. (I wonder how I was left unpunished for that).

So for `i == 1` and `i == 2` `str[i][count] == '\0'` and the loop breaks.

Comment: I am surprise with the result from the second iteration of for loop, the output suggested that on the second iteration, str[1][26] == '\0'while the actual string is ended at 21 characters. the program should receive some garbage value, right?

Comment: @dragosht What exactly happens to the remaining spaces of the array? How are they utilized? I allotted 30 characters, 27 are utilized including the `\0`, what about the remaining 3?

Comment: @someone_smiley `\0` is garbage in its own way.

Comment: You make right point, but I think it will depend on compiler,@someone_smipley

Comment: I thing \0 means null every string end with \0 in c, @quemtin

Comment: thanks guy for answering. i gather that, some compiler will set value '\0' to all remaining unassigned char. Am i right?

Comment: @someone_smiley I didn't get what you meant when you said `str[1][26] == '\0'`, the number of characters are `21` in the `str[1]`. How can the compiler count it to `26`?

Comment: @VSP : No. The number of character for every string is 30. but only 21 were assigned a value for second string :)

Comment: @someone_smiley So the 22 character is to be the `\0`, that's where the execution of the loop should stop. isn't it?

Comment: in your declaration "char str[][30]", u asked the compiler to reserve 30 character space for each string. it is now upto you that how many of them you are actually going to use.

Comment: Yes. if the count variable were inside for loop, the program would found '\0' at 22nd character of second string

Comment: I get that part, but according to the condition `while(str[i][count] != '\0')` the loop should stop executing right where it encounters the  `\0` isn't that right?

Comment: @someone_smiley I am too talking about the variable `count` which is declared inside.

Comment: @VSP loop working well it work fine at first time but then it check that str[2][26] is null? and it get YES so cont value never change and same thing happened to str[3]

Comment: @Jageen Instead of `while(str[i][count] != '\0')` I can also use `while(str[i][count])` as ASCII value of `\0` is `0` so the condition will automatically becomes false when it encounters `\0`. Is it right?

Comment: yes, you can. But people usually dont do that. personally i prefer full compare with '\0' as it is easier to look at first glance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you are declaring it outside the for loop, your count is not reset to 0, so for your string str[0] your while loop is working. but after it displays the count value in output as 26, from then its value is not reset to 0. So your inner while loop is not executing for str[1] and str[2] and it direclty prints the value 26 as before.

So for doing that either you can declare your count inside for loop or you can also declare it outside the for loop but reset it in for loop before excuting while loop like:

```
for(;i<strcount;++i)   
{
     count = 0; //Reset it to 0
     while(str[i][count] != '\0')
      ++count;

     printf("\n\nNumber of Characters in STR[%d] = %d",i,count);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Practice.c` you have declared `Count` in the scope of main. but in `Test.c` you have declared `Count` in the scope of `while`. whenever it encounter `int count=0`in while,so it makes `count` to 0. For every string it will count the characters from 0th position.

But in `Practice.c` due to scope with in the main, after counting the length of the First string `count` holds the value of 26. so for second string `while(str[i][count] != '\0')` will fail because `str[1][26]!='\0'`. so it will print the value 26. for third string also the same value it will print.